# Delphi not create APK for android project

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I install Delphi 10.3 Rio in other computer and try to create android app. I install android SDK 19 and set in up with delphi. But after compile my project I see no *APK fil*e was created.

I install that (Delphi 10.3 Rio ) to my computer than have delphi XE7 with same *android SDK* and  work well. After I install Delphi 10.3 Rio on my computer I see same problem and apk not created and our delphi XE7 Suffered same problem and not created APK too.

**Update  :**

When I use deploy, my delphi xe 7 work good, but 10.3 is still having problem. When I do deploy, an error shows up in the event window:

> [PAClient Error] Error: E2312 Unable to execute C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\PlatformSDKs\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4\Aapt.exe" package -f -M "C:\New folder\Android\Debug\Project1\AndroidManifest.xml" -F "C:\New folder\Android\Debug\Project1\bin\Project1-unsigned.apk" -I "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\PlatformSDKs\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\platforms\android-19\android.jar" -S "C:\New folder\Android\Debug\Project1\res" -A "C:\New folder\Android\Debug\Project1\assets" "C:\New folder\Android\Debug\Project1\library" "C:\New folder\Android\Debug\Project1\classes"' (Error 1)

thanks to @mirtheil

Comment: I uninstall RAD Studio XE10 but problem is still Persist!build success but no _APK file_

Comment: Are you building or deploying?  In my copy of Delphi 10.3, I have to Deploy to get the APK.  Build only builds the project while deploy creates the APK.  Then again, I don't have an Android device hooked up the development machine.

Comment: Is there more to the error?

Comment: Yes. I wrote the error

Comment: I do believe you have to connect a device the first time to produce it.

Comment: It appears you're using a horribly out of date SDK. I suggest following the steps, here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Release_Notes#Android

Comment: I use android SDK 22 and connect my device to run in to that but problem is happen too

Answer (score 3):

thank to all guys !
It has been solved by update SDK to API 28.